# Radius of a power series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, power-series

We have the power series:

$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_nz^n
$$

The radius of convergence of that series is $R$.

Now I need to find the radius of convergence for:

$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_nc^nz^n, \quad c \in \mathbb C
$$

The answers say that the new series converges for:

$$
|cz| < R
$$

And then says that because it holds that:

$$
|cz| = |c||z|
$$

We can conclude that the radius of convergence of the new series is: (for $|c| \neq 0$)

$$
R' = \frac{R}{|c|}
$$

Why is the new radius not $R$, as we said that $|cz| < R$? Why do they go ahead and find $R'$?

Answer (score 2):

$\sum a_nz^n$ converges if $|z|<R$ and diverges if $ |z|>R$.

thus

$\sum a_n(cz)^n$ converges if $|cz|<R $ 
or $|z|<\frac{R}{|c|}$

and diverges if $|cz|>R$ or $|z|>\frac{R}{|c|}$

hence, by definition, $$R'=\frac{R}{|c|}$$

$c $ is a real or a complex $ (\ne 0)$.

Comment: Why are you looking only at $z$, why $|cz| < R$ is not the converges we need? why you go to $z$, thats my question, the algebra i understand.

Comment: Nevermind, understood, the $c$ is a scalar.

Comment: Why are you commeting this? Why it is connected to the question?